# new Date() and split() cross-browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, date, split

I'm trying to make a date to appear as `Fri, Feb 17 2012` instead of `Friday, February 17, 2012`

Here is my code:

```
     var n = new Date(),
        ampm = 'am',
        h = n.getHours(),
        m = n.getMinutes(),
        s = n.getSeconds();
     if (h >= 12) {
        if (h > 12) h -= 12;
        ampm = 'pm'
     }
     if (h < 10) h = '0' + h;
     if (m < 10) m = '0' + m;
     t = n.toLocaleDateString();
     var d = 
         t.split(',')[0].substring(0, 3)
         + ', '
         + t.split(',')[1].substring(1, 4)
         + ' '
         + t.split(',')[1].split(' ')[2]
         + t.split(',')[2]
         + ', '
         + ' '
         + h + ':' + m + ' ' + ampm;
     var e = Math.round((new Date() - new Date('2012/01/01').getTime()) / 1000);
     var f = [1];
     var a = [];
     var i = 0;
     alert(d);​
```

Now this works on some browsers but it doesnt on others. Some browsers show 17, 201, undefinedundefined, and some  browsers show what I am looking for.

Can anyone spot what I am missing?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nxyum/

Works on:

```
Windows: Chrome, Safari
Mac: Chrome, Opera
```

​

Doesn't work:

```
Windows: Firefox, Opera, IE
Mac: Firefox, Safari
```

Comment: Are you missing the browsers it doesn't work on?

Comment: @Walkerneo Yes sir. Browsers that are missing are the ones not working.

Comment: What I meant was it would help if you told us the browsers it doesn't work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what you are doing with your code...It's easy to output a date formatted any way you like-

```
Date.prototype.shortString= function(){
    var D= this, 
    shortdays= ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    shortmonths= ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 
    'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

    return  [shortdays[D.getDay()], ', ', shortmonths[D.getMonth()], ' ', 
    D.getDate(), ' ', D.getFullYear()].join('');
}
new Date().shortString()

/*  returned value: (String)
Fri, Feb 17 2012
*/
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string. What doesn't work in my code is this: t.split(',')[1].substring(1, 4)

Comment: @jQuerybeast Try again. A comma was missing after the first item of the result array.

Comment: I dont need to find where my code was wrong. You answer just works. Thanks much